# Hreflang on product pages, how Google will treat the rest of the site?

Tags: seo, hreflang, technical-seo

We're planning on introducing hreflang on specific pages on our site (mostly product).

Scenario:
Main US site: https://www.example.com/
Hreflang will be introduced only on product pages, example:

```
https://www.example.com/fr/products/product-A/
```

So if a user from France searches for the product and lands on Product-A and he wants to browse back to the homepage, should he be taken to:

```
A: https://www.example.com/
B: https://www.example.com/fr/
```

We are trying to avoid the B destination as our homepage doesn’t provide anything different for French people, only our products (currency, price).

Product pages are the only that are deliver alternative content, the homepage and categories are not providing anything different so introducing hreflang there should be wrong.

Whats the approach when you add hreflang to a selected pages only?

Comment: Are you just using hreflang tag to show currency and price? If this is the case, an IP based currency is better than having different product pages assuming your website is small and you are not looking for accurate results for the time being.

Comment: Are both A and B in French?   If not, B should be in French which would be better for users.

Comment: Mostly yes, however im looking for accuracy on the results.  @StephenOstermiller Currently site B above doesn't exist but we started building, it will take some time so for the time being i was wondering the product pages under /fr/ sub-folder have no homepage should i keep them under the main homepage?